# How to setup Virtual Gifting between members with Store

Tags: expresso-store, zoo-visitor, payment-gateway

Here's what I would like to do, I would like my site members to be able to send virtual gifts to each other, the problem is how to associate that member A sent a gift to member B? And also how to retrieve a list of all the gifts that a certain member has received/gifted?

I'm already using Exp:resso Store on the site and also Zoo Visitor.

Even though Credits apparently doesn't work with Store, ideally these purchases would be made with credits, so that the members could use the credits they received by participating on the site to send free gifts, for example.

Any thoughts?

Also has anyone ever worked with a payment system like Boku?

ETA: I think I've figured out how to decode the stored modifiers for purchased items, so part of my problem is solved, I can write a plugin to retrieve the data. Nevertheless if you have any input related to the implementation of such system, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: You might contact DevDemon about a beta version of Credits that works with Store. I know it was under development a while back.

Answer (score 1):

Last I heard there was a beta version of Credits with support for Store, so it's worth contacting DevDemon if you want access to that.

To access the list of items purchased for a user you can simply check the `exp_store_order_items` table. The item modifiers are stored as JSON (Store 2) or a Base64 encoded serialized array (Store 1).